# Difference between software development interfacing terms: API, Web API, REST API, Web Services, SOAP Services

Tags: rest, web, web-applications

**API vs Web API vs REST API vs Web Services vs SOAP Services**

I came across this question in interviews many times. Also, I found that many people get confused when someone asks them to explain any one of these terms, they start mixing the terms.

I have gone through many contents on the web, but **I never found any page where all these terms are explained well at a single location.**

**Can anyone explain these terms and how they are interrelated?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that these terms are used so interchangeably there really isn't much of a strict definition.

In my opinion, an API is almost anything you use to interface another piece of software/hardware. This could be command-line, a HTTP API, native mobile APIs, native web APIs, methods to interact with GPIO, L2C, ... different protocols.

Most of what is programmed uses many layers of different APIs (abstractions), a method is *technically* an API. You get the point?

A web API would typically use HTTP(S) or similar technology in order to expose it's API. You *could* also consider a "web" API to be anything that exposes it's API across the internet, over TCP for example, or using gRPC, etc..

A REST API is a particular type of Web API, defining a standard for designing/developing stateless APIs exposed over HTTP(s), this standard is adopted by most modern APIs, although a few aren't RESTful, more RESTish, but I digress.[1] RESTful APIs will have endpoints like: `GET /users/1` in order to perform CRUD operations, and will usually accept/response JSON.

Web services == Web API in my opinion, not a lot of difference, a service (in my mind) can be an API, it *could* also be a service that exposes no API and only repeats a task.

I'm not going to comment on SOAP, I was very young when SOAP was around, however I believe it used XML.

EDIT: This is a very broad topic, and would honestly spark some discussion depending on age, experience and background. But this is my opinion on the terms you outlined above.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer